# question about recognizing function and module in python

Tags: python-3.x

My questions are about code with this format:

```
 name1.name2()
```

Question1: I saw this format in python a lot. I want to make sure is it ture that every time I see this format name1 is a module and name2() is a function of this module?

Question2: Is it possible to have name1.name2  (without () in front of name2)? and in this format is name2 a module or function?(My Thought on question2: name2 cant be function because it need "()" to be a function But I am not sure if it is a module or even we have this format.)

Comment: As for Q1: Compare with ``name1 = [3, 2, 4]`` followed by ``name1.sort()``. As for Q2: Compare with ``str.strip`` in ``' '.join(map(str.strip, [" Hello", " World "]))``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1: Actually you cant be sure at all since it's not necessary for the `name1` to be a module. It can be almost anything. And anyhing in Python is an Object :)
The `name2`, as a result, is probably a method of that Object. So the `name1` can be an instance of a class, the class itself, a string, an integer, a module or a package, whatever ...

Answer 2: Yes, it is possible to have that format. The `name2` in this case may again be a lot of things, it can be anything that is defined in the `name1` object. It can be a property, a function in the module, a module in a package, a method of the Object or anything else.